# getting nonetype after using numpy.fill

Tags: python, numpy

I want to use numpy array as the following:

```
room_1_class_value = numpy.empty(len(room_1_indices[0])).fill(1)
```

`room_1_indices[0]` is an array, and I can see the output of that array. But why I get "None" for "room_1_class_value"?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're not assigning a numpy array to `room_1_class_value`. You're assigning to it the value of the `fill(1)` function call. This function doesn't return anything.

Try:

```
room_1_class_value = numpy.empty(len(room_1_indices[0]))
room_1_class_value.fill(1)
```